# Solving Quadratic Equation involving Natural Logarithm

Tags: logarithms, quadratics

This question came out in the Examination for Japanese University Admission for International Students (EJU).

$$\qquad e^{2x}-ae^{x}+b=0 \cdots (eq.1)$$

$$Let \quad t={e}^{x}$$

$$\qquad {t}^{2}-at+b=0 \cdots (eq.2)$$

The roots of this quadratic equation (eq.2) are

$\qquad \log_{{q}^{2}} p,\;$ and $\;\log_{{p}^{3}} q$, where $p>1$ ,$\;$ $q>1$

**Question**: Solve for $x$ when the value of $a$ is smallest.

**Hints**: These are the hints provided. How do I use these hints to solve this question? (I only manage to find out $a$ and $b$ by using Sum of Root and Product of Root)

1. By Product of Roots $\;\to\;$ $b=\log_{{q}^{2}} p \times \log_{{p}^{3}} q$

$$b=\frac{1}{6}$$

2. By Sum of Roots $\;\to\;$ $a=\log_{{q}^{2}} p + \log_{{p}^{3}} q$

$$a = \frac{1}{2}{log_q p} + \frac{1}{3}{log_p q}$$

3. Given that $$log_p q > A$$

$\quad$When 
$$\quad log_p q = \frac{\sqrt{B}}{C} \quad$$ $a$ has the smallest value of,

$$\qquad\qquad a= \frac{\sqrt{D}}{E} \quad$$  where $A,B,C,D,E$ are integers of one digit

4. The root of (eq.1), $x$ is in the form of

$$\qquad x = -\frac{F}{G}{\log_e H}$$ where $F, G, H$ are integers of one digit

Comment: Is the question to find $A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H$ or you've added those variables on your own?

Comment: $A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H$ are hints provided by the question, which means finding the values of these variables will lead to the final answer - the root of (eq.1)

Answer (score 1):

Hint :

Since the roots of thus equation are real, you have the condition that discriminant $\ge 0$.

Thus, the minimum value of $a$ is

$$a^2-4b \ge 0 \implies a_{min} ^2=4b =\frac 23$$

Hence $$a_{\text{min}}=-\sqrt{\frac 23}$$

Also use that $$\log_q p=\frac{1}{\log_p q}$$

Comment: From the hint above,
$a = \frac{1}{2}{log_q p} + \frac{1}{3}{log_p q} \;$

since $\; log_p q > 0 \quad$

shouldn't $\; a_{min} = \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}} > 0 \;$ instead of $-\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}$?

Comment: Where is it written that $\log_p q >0$? $a$ isn't given to be positive.